# Is it safe have more than one version of java?

Tags: openjdk, jre

This question popped up when I tried to download a game for dolphin emu. The site isohunt recommended I use vuze and vuze requires jre. Silly me, as a windows noob, I immediately thought I d have to have the latest update. Well I got openjdk 7 and then I realized and I had openjdk 6 and 7. So I deleted the openjdk6 stuff and now vuze/azureus says I need openjdk 6.

So any advice about any of this would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you actually just manually delete it, or did you uninstall it using `apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre`?

Comment: If the package was removed, it can simply be reinstalled (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre`). If the files associated with it were *manually* deleted then it needs to be *reinstalled* (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --reinstall install openjdk-6-jre`).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe to have more than one version of Java installed. Ubuntu uses the [Debian alternatives system](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) to make this work safely and smoothly.